# Bind multiple checkbox in page from database table or stored procedure in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, database, checkbox, webforms, bind

I have number of checkbox in a page, and want to bind those from database table together, how can I do this?

Thanks

This is my example:

```
<table class="table table-hover" dir="rtl" style="text-align: right; direction: rtl">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="text-align: left">Call Date:</td>
        <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-4">
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="lblCallDate" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chCallDate" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="text-align: left">Call Time:</td>
        <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-4">
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="lblCallTime" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chCallTime" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="text-align: left">Problem title:</td>
        <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-4">
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="lblProblem" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chProblem" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="text-align: left">Problem Descreptions:</td>
        <td class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-7 col-xs-4">
            <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="lblProblemDesc" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chProblemDesc" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, every checkbox is in different location, I have a table with checked column and want to bind those check box from that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more with example about what you want to achieve?  You want to bind multiple columns from one table or values from multiple rows for colum?

Answer (score 0):

Try This: I have used Dictionary in this example, you can use List of predefined classes as well.

Assuming you have a method that returns a Dictionary.

1> .aspx Page:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="lstCities">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

2> .cs page_load:

```
lstCities.DataSource = getCities();
lstCities.DataValueField = "Key";
lstCities.DataTextField = "Value";
lstCities.DataBind();
```

3> getCities:

```
protected Dictionary<string, string> getCities()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> x = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        x.Add("1", "City 1");
        x.Add("2", "City 2");
        x.Add("3", "City 3");
        x.Add("4", "City 4");
        return x;
    }
```